# form Serialize is not accepting Image in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit data with ajax. But form serialize is not accepting Image. Other fields are coming correctly. What is the problem?

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = $(form).serialize();

$.ajax({
  url: "{{ route('admin.faculty_tabs.store')}}",
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Data from file inputs is not serialized. It's value is just a fake path to the uploaded file. If you need to pass the actual file/s you should use the FormData interface, as @ismamz suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```js
var data = new FormData(form);
```

And set:

```js
{
  ...
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
}
```

[FormData - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: There is no data in `data`